# This type of step does not support compressed syntax

Tags: circleci

When I try to change from CircleCI `run` in the code below from

```
deploy-prod:
  executor: aws-cli/default
  steps:
    - attach_workspace:
        at: client

    - aws-cli/install
    - aws-cli/configure:
        profile-name: default

    - run: cd client && aws s3 sync build/ s3://www.example.com --delete
```

to
[`deploy`](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#deploy) which is a special step for deploying artifacts

```
    - deploy: cd client && aws s3 sync build/ s3://www.example.com --delete
```

I got the error

> In step 6 definition: This type of step does not support compressed
>   syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not clear what **compressed syntax** means in this case and cannot find anything useful online.

Turns out `&&` is compressed syntax here. After changing to

```
    // ...
    - deploy:
        command: |
          cd client
          aws s3 sync build/ s3://www.example.com --delete
```

it works again. Hopefully it will help who might meet same issue in future.